# Error al recorrer un elemento dentro de otro html

Tags: javascript

Tengo un HTML, y desde javascript quiero acceder de la siguiente forma:

`var principal = document.getElementById("main");
 var parrafo1 = principal.getElementById("parrafo1");`

Pero en tiempo de ejecución em arroja el siguiente error en la consola:

```js
var principal = document.getElementById("main");
var parrafo1 = principal.getElementById("parrafo1");
```

```html
<div id="main">
        <p id="parrafo1">Este es el primer párrafo</p>
```

`index.html:35 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementById is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.cambiarTextos`

Qué está produciendo el error?

Comment: Eso es por que la variable "principal" almacena un elemento HTML, en la variable parrafo1 usted intento acceder al metodo "getElementById" cuando esta no esta definida en "principal" porque ese metodo es exclusivo del objeto "document", por lo tanto para, acceder al elemento parrafo1 haga lo mismo que en la variable principal.

Comment: Cual seria su idea al acceder al elemento del párrafo? Al usar la función "getElementById" puedes acceder directamente a buscar el id del párrafo con la misma función de la misma forma que encuentra el "main".

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), así como otros métodos parecidos, son exclusivos de la interfaz [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document) de la API Web.

Cuando tu llamas a dicho método, el resultado será un [Elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element) del [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM), que no es igual a la interfaz `document`.

Es por ello que recibes el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementById is not a function

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr lo que te propones debes trabajar con los nodos hijos del elemento que estás capturando. Esto lo logras usando la propiedad [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) de tu [elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element).

Lo que devuelve la propiedad `childNodes` es una lista (entiéndase iterable) de los elementos hijos que lo componen.

Luego puedes recorrer dicho iterable usando un bucle `for`.

Sin embargo, para asegurarte que puedes recorrer un iterable, el mismo debe existir, para ello nos aseguramos que el elemento padre contenga hijos, usando el método [`hasChildNodes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes), que devolverá un valor booleano dependiendo de si el padre tiene hijos o no.

Una vez que estás recorriendo la lista de elementos hijos, puedes usar la propiedad [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/id) del elemento que estás iterando para determinar si se corresponde con el que estás buscando.

Un ejemplo sería:

```js
const elementoPadre = document.getElementById('padre');

if(elementoPadre.hasChildNodes()){
  const hijos = elementoPadre.childNodes;
  for (let i = 0; i < hijos.length; i++) {
    if(hijos[i].id === 'parrafo2') {
      console.log('Parrafo 2:');
      console.log(hijos[i].innerHTML);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">
  <p id="parrafo1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p id="parrafo2">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p id="parrafo3"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  <p id="parrafo4">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.